# Swing: How to make JFrame scrolling smooth?

Tags: java, macos, swing

I'm creating a very simple Swing GUI consisting of a scrollable text area. However, I'm having some problems with the responsiveness of the UI. Here is the class I am using to try some different configurations:

```
public class ComponentSample {
  public void createWindow() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea(getFillerText(), 40, 120);

    setViews(frame, textArea);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private void setViews(JFrame frame, TextArea textArea) {
    ...
  }

  private String getFillerText() {
    String threeLines = "Why isn't scrolling smooth? \nSteve Jobs would not approve\n\n";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      stringBuilder.append(threeLines);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
      () -> new ComponentSample().createWindow()
    );
  }
}
```

Here I have tried several different method bodies for the `setViews()` method with the following results:

**Adding textArea in a JPanel**

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(textArea);
    frame.add(panel);
```

Scrolls by 1 or 2 rows instead of by pixel (not smooth). Also flashes white when scrolling quickly (repainting issue?).

**Adding textArea in a Viewport**

```
    JViewport viewport = new JViewport();
    viewport.setView(textArea);
    frame.add(viewport);
```

Same results as JPanel.

**Adding textArea directly**

```
    frame.add(textArea);
```

Same results as JPanel.

**Adding textArea in a ScrollPane**

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    frame.add(scrollPane);
```

Doesn't seem to handle scrolling properly - it doesn't respond to the scrollwheel (only clicking the scrollbar). Scrolls by ~0.5 row instead of by pixel.

Also, in each of the above cases, when the scrollbar is dragged with the mouse it prints the following (error? IDEA shows it in red) to the stdout:

```
2016-03-17 09:45:33.413 java[40977:2845515] inOptions: {
    JavaCUIThumbStartKey = 0;
    "is.flipped" = 0;
    kCUIOrientationKey = kCUIOrientVertical;
    kCUIThumbProportionKey = "0.1328903585672379";
    max = 0;
    pressedpart = 0;
    state = normal;
    value = 0;
    widget = scrollbar;
}
2016-03-17 09:45:33.413 java[40977:2845515] inOptions: {
    JavaCUIThumbStartKey = 0;
    "is.flipped" = 0;
    kCUIOrientationKey = kCUIOrientVertical;
    kCUIThumbProportionKey = "0.1328903585672379";
    max = 0;
    pressedpart = 0;
    state = normal;
    value = 0;
    widget = scrollbar;
}
2016-03-17 09:45:33.414 java[40977:2845515] outHitPart = 0
```

If it matters, I'm on OS X.

**My question** is how can I make it scroll smoothly (pixel by pixel) without flashing white and without printing errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As camickr pointed out, I should have been using a `JTextArea` instead of a `TextArea`. That fixed the white flashes which I assume were repaint issues.

To make scrolling smooth without being laggy, I had to adjust the unit increment, which is the number of pixels the view will move by when one of the scrollbar arrows is pressed:

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(1);
```

This ended up causing a bunch of lag because when I scrolled the program had to continuously calculate and redraw the screen at 1px intervals. To fix this, I had to change the viewport scroll mode:

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE);
```

It turns out it was using `BLIT_SCROLL_MODE` by default.

What I have now is an app that scrolls smoothly (doesn't jump pixels), doesn't lag and doesn't flash white when I scroll too fast. That's pretty good progress. The one thing I haven't managed to figure out is that now scrolling is fairly slow - eg giving the mouse wheel a good spin doesn't get me too far down the page. This is obviously because I'm only moving one pixel per notch (that's what `setUnitIncrement()` did). What I want is to go a good distance down the page when I scroll agressively, just like in other apps like Chrome or Intellij. But for now I'm pretty happy with where I've got it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a TextArea that is an AWT component.

Instead you should be using a `JTextArea` which is the Swing component.

The basic code is:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
frame.add( scrollPane );
```

Edit:

> it still scrolls by full rows instead of by pixel

A scroll pane support the concept of unit scrolling and block scrolling. Unit scrolling for a JTextArea is one row of text and block scrolling is the size of the viewport window. When using a mouse the scrolling (in windows) is based on a multiple of the unit scrolling which on my component is 3 * the unit scrolling.

If your concern is the amount of scrolling done by the mouse wheel then maybe you can use the [Mouse Wheel Controller](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/mouse-wheel-controller/) which allows you to change the multiplier to a different value. So you could set it to 1.

If you concern is the actual unit increment amount then you can change the default by using:

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(1);
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the repaint problems. However, it still scrolls by full rows instead of by pixel, making the animation very coarse-grained. How can I get to scroll smoothly? Also the (error?) message is still printed to the stdout when dragging the scroll bar. Not sure if that's expected.

Comment: thanks. I used `setUnitIncrement()` as you suggested. This makes scrolling much smoother but unfortunately laggy. From reading docs I gather that the entire view is being recomputed on every pixel scroll. I added a `JViewport` which, according to the docs, only updates the neccessary area and also preloads the entire component. I now have a `JTextArea` inside a `JViewport` inside a `JScrollPane` inside a `JFrame`. However, this causes scrollbars to disappear probably because the viewport itself is within the size of the scrollpanel. How can I get scrollbars for the text area?

Comment: @tytk, I gave you the 3 lines of code you need to use a JTextArea in a JScrollPane. You never have to play with the viewport. The viewport is managed by the scroll pane. I have never experienced laggy scrolling, but I use Windows. I suggest you post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so people that use OSX can test your code and see if they experience the same problem. Otherwise I don't know what to say. There is no magic to using a scroll pane.